# Is the iPhone always using Wifi (instead of cellular data network) when connected?

Tags: iphone, data-transfer

When I'm in range and connected to particular Wifi, having cellular data transmission enabled at the same time, will the iPhone always use the Wifi connection?

Or can the app developer choose which network has priority (e.g. always use cellular data transmission and not Wifi)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

IPhone will use the cellular connection for push notifications at any time, unless

```
Settings > General > Network > Cellular Data
```

is turned off.

Also, if the lock screen is on, then iPhone is connected to the cellular network, not wifi.

IPad is always connected to wifi, lock screen or no.

Comment: are you sure?: _if the lock screen is on, then iPhone is connected to the cellular network, not wifi._

Answer (score 1):

I believe you cannot chose programmatically whether to use the WiFi or the cellular data connection.

If the iPhone has a WiFi network available, it will automatically use it, otherwise, it will fallback on the cellular data connection.